# How Create Sequence number in Controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I am working on a project which is an E-health patient Gateway.

I want to generate a number (int type) against a submit form from View to Controller (When phlebotomist receives the blood sample he will check the box and click on submit button). This number is the patient's blood sample number that will be generated in my controller and will be saved in the database. I am using the logic below to create the number but it always gives me zero.

Kindly let me know how I can create numbers one by one in sequence and store in database?

```
public ActionResult AddSampleTest(int Pid, int Tid, int Stid, string   Comment ,string testDate,int DotorID)
    {
        int sampleNumber=1;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] sample = new int[50000];
        rnd.Next();
        for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= sample.Length; ctr++)
        {
            sampleNumber=sample[ctr + 1];

        }




        string sampleno = sampleNumber.ToString();
        DateTime TestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(testDate);
        int  Recomended_Test_DoctorID = DotorID;

        // Update the Sample Status 
        PatientTest objpatientTest = db.PatientTests.Where(x => x.PatientID == Pid && x.Testid == Tid && x.SubTestId == Stid && x.Date==TestDate &&x.DoctorId== Recomended_Test_DoctorID).FirstOrDefault();
        objpatientTest.SampleStatus = "Sample Received";
        objpatientTest.SampleNumber = sampleno;
        db.SaveChanges();

        var name = User.Identity.Name;
        int Lid = db.LabAttendantRecords.Where(x => x.Name == name).Select(x => x.User_id).FirstOrDefault();



        LabTestSample obj = new LabTestSample();
            obj.labtestid = Tid;
            obj.PatientId = Pid;
            obj.subtestid = Stid;
            obj.labAtendid = Lid;
            obj.date = DateTime.Now.Date;
            obj.sampleReceived = true;


            obj.Comment = sampleno;
            db.LabTestSamples.Add(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("TestSampleNumber", "LabAttendantDashboard", new { sampleno});

        // Use This for add Result
        return RedirectToAction("SubTest", "LabAttendantDashboard", new { Pid, Tid, Stid });
    }
```

Comment: Where do you assign the random number to a variable ?

Comment: Thanks SiHa , I  assigns at the end of for

Comment: Thanks SiHa , I  assigns at the end of for loop  you can see below              string sampleno = sampleNumber.ToString();

Comment: Your problem is sampleNumber=sample[ctr + 1] that will be always 0. You don't use the random value.

Answer (score 1):

`sampleNumber` is always 0 because each element in `sample` is 0.
If you want it to be a random number you need to do something like :

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int sampleNumber = rnd.Next();
string sampleno = sampleNumber.ToString();
```

If you need to be sure that the sample number is unique, you should use a Guid :

```
string sampleno = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks Cubi, Your logic is Creating Random Number but I think Created Random numbers can be same. How can i can make sure random number is not be same to previous  created random number?                                                                Every patient blood sample,s number must be different  and not be repeat .